# Compiler installation

Tags: compiler-construction, hardware

I started to learn two computer languages two years ago. But there are many things that I am trying to understand. For example I would like to know if it is possible to install a compiler (for example a C compiler) on a computer without an operating system installed on it?

Comment: It would be difficult and custom to your hardware, but I don't see why not. Have fun trying to find one, though...

Comment: To add to Jon's answer, you'd have to pretty much embed a mini-OS into your compiler code so that the compiler would be able to do basic things like talk to the hard drive, the keyboard, the graphics card, etc.  All the sorts of things an OS does for you.

Comment: A mini-OS? If a computer has a cpu, can't you use the assembly language to make programs?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Forth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) - it is not normally compiled language, but can be used on hardware without OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an operating system.. you don't have anywhere to install anything.

Comment: Have you ever heard of a hard drive?

Comment: Are all operating systems written in assembly?

Comment: No, they generally aren't anymore.  However, the operating system source is compiled on an existing machine to get the binaries that are  placed into the operating system installer.  (And even when they were/are written in assembly, they haven't been hand-assembled in decades).

Comment: @user1256053 

Not exactly... Modern operating systems aren't written in *full* assembly. For example, Windows is written in C, C++ and Assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

Well what would be the practical use of doing this ? 
the only thing i can think of is if you are trying to embed it into some hardware. 
I think it is possible just a bit odd to try to do that. Beside a compiler is supposed to compile code.. so how will you input your code without OS ??